# How do you apply for a US tourism B2 visa as an Indian national living in Spain?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, tourist-visas, spain

I am an indian national residing in spain for the past 5 years. I have temporary residence here. I want to apply for a tourism visa to US but do not see Spain as an option when making my profile on cgifederal. Is this possible or do I have to apply from my home country India? Can I apply from another European country?

Comment: You should be able to appy from spain, if you are residing in spain for long term.

Comment: You certainly do not need to go to India.  What is cgifederal and why do you think you need to create a profile there to apply for a visa? Did you read [https://es.usembassy.gov/visas](https://es.usembassy.gov/visas)?